# Creating a chart with the range being the area the user has selected - Object does not support this property or method

Tags: excel, vba

So I need to create a graph and the data that is in said graph needs to be the range that the user currently has highlighted, I've done this fine and the graph creates but the error "Object does not support this property or method" is thrown, can someone please help me fix this error, I've tried multiple different ways of creating charts and this is the only one that gets close to working

My code for creating a chart:

```
Sub CreateChart()
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
ActiveChart.ChartType = xlBarClustered
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=ActiveSheet.range(Selection.Address)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few possible answers to your question.
First, if you run your macro user could have some range selected. It means that you only need the following code to succeed:

```
Sub CreateChart()
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
    ActiveChart.ChartType = xlBarClustered
End Sub
```

If you need to set reference to selected range anyway, you could do it this way:

```
Sub CreateChart_modif()
    Dim rngSel As Range
    Set rngSel = Selection

    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
    ActiveChart.ChartType = xlBarClustered
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData source:=rngSel
End Sub
```

Comment: Worked perfectly thanks, I didn't realize that it would create the chart with the selection the user has be default. Thankyou.

Comment: +1. I would only caution OP that "data that is in said graph needs to be the range that the user currently has highlighted," -- this approach leaves a lot of room for error.